# algorithm2e linesnumbered long text not indenting correctly

Tags: formatting, algorithms, algorithm2e

> Set up

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate. All other submissions i've seen on this topic is how to correct text indentation when using `\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}` however as i am using  `\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}` non of the old solutions are working.

Given a long piece of text to be placed within my algorithm, see below:

> MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} %remove \lipsum[#]

%ALGORITHM CODE
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}


%-----------------------------BEGIN-----------------------------
\begin{document}

 \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \SetKwInOut{Define}{Define}

    \underline{Initialise:} Conditions for Algorithm\;
    \Define{define functions for algorithm}
    \Input{input of algoithm}
    \Output{Output}

    \underline{Run through algorithm In Full:} 

      {

        \hspace{5pt}  \textbf{Start}:

      }
      {

       \hspace{15pt}   \lipsum[1]

      }
      {

      \hspace {5pt} \textbf{End}

      }

    \caption{Name of algoithm and details etc...}
\end{algorithm} 


\end{document}
```

> Goal

How to correct the code on line  `\hspace{15pt}   \lipsum[1]` so that the entire paragraph is indented correctly in line with the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fairly common from the manual that the `{algorithm2e}` is optimized to mathematical input. However in your case as your algorithm contains a large amount of text, you have two options:

> Option 1)

In this case we write the paragraph by indention on all subsequent lines following the first. Then in this case i would suggest replacing `\hspace{15pt}   \lipsum[1]` by the following:

`\leftskip 10pt\relax \lipsum[1]` , or more compactly as:

```
   \bgroup 
    \parindent 0pt 
    \leftskip 5pt 

    \textbf{Start}: 

    \leftskip 10pt\relax \lipsum[1] 

    \textbf{End} 

    \egroup
```

> Option 2)

In this case we are creating a paragraph in a block which is shifted to the left i.e. removing the indentation on the first line, which is normally done with `\noindent` proceeding the text (depending on which LATEX compiler you are using). Hence to be on the safe side for spacing purposes i have used the following:

```
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \SetKwInOut{Define}{Define}

    \underline{Initialise:} Conditions for Algorithm\;
    \Define{define functions for algorithm}
    \Input{input of algoithm}
    \Output{Output}

    \underline{Run through algorithm In Full:} 

      {

        \hspace{5pt}  \textbf{Start}:

      }
      {

       \hspace{15pt} my life is lonely 

      }

      {

          \bgroup\leftskip 15pt \hspace{1pt} \lipsum[1] \par\egroup
      }      
      {

      \hspace {5pt} \textbf{End}

      }

    \caption{Name of algoithm and details etc...}
\end{algorithm}
```

Which gives the desired result.